# Как добавить ProgressBar, Microsoft Visual Studio, С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Нужно окно которое буде высвечиваться пока "бат" файл, совершает манипуляции на заднем фоне.
Взял  Microsoft Visual Studio, С++. Хочу с минимумом подключаемых библиотек.
Получился этот код

```
// WindowsProject1.cpp : Определяет точку входа для приложения.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "WindowsProject1.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна


// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Разместите код здесь.

    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1));

    MSG msg;

    // Цикл основного сообщения:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Регистрирует класс окна.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT1));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   ЦЕЛЬ: Сохраняет маркер экземпляра и создает главное окно
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В этой функции маркер экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится главное окно программы.
//        исключенные переменные WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, WS_DISABLED

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить маркер экземпляра в глобальной переменной 

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, _T("Проверка обновления программ"), WS_SYSMENU,
       (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - 250), (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - 150), 500, 300, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT    - Отрисовка главного окна
//  WM_DESTROY  - отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR str[] = _T("ПРОВЕРЯЕМ НАЛИЧИЕ И ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ ПРОГРАММ\r\n НЕ ОТКЛЮЧАЙТЕ КОМПЬЮТЕР");
    HWND wnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    HDC dc = GetDC(wnd);
    RECT rc;
    HFONT font;
    HGDIOBJ old;
    font = CreateFont(-20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0u, 0U, 0U, ANSI_CHARSET, 0U, 0U, 0U, 0U, _T("calibri"));
    old = SelectObject(dc, font);
    GetClientRect(wnd, &rc);
    rc.top = 10;
    SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor(dc, 0x00000000);  // цвет текста(зелённый)

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Добавьте сюда любой код прорисовки, использующий HDC...
            DrawText(dc, str, lstrlen(str), &rc, DT_CENTER);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:

        SelectObject(dc, old);
        ReleaseDC(wnd, dc);
        DeleteObject(font);
        getchar();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Не могу понять как сюда любую анимацию, подумал что хорошо бы ProgressBar который без конца крутит пробегающую полоску.

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/progress-bar-control-reference А еще ваше приложение создает шрифт при каждом вызове `WndProc`.

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку. А куда можно вынести "font = CreateFont(...."  ?

Comment: По этой ссылке что вы дали описана возможность запуска через  CreateWindowEx. На сколько я понял то это создание отдельного окна с ProgressBar а хотелось бы его отображать в окне рядом с текстом.

Comment: CreateWindowEx позволяет создавать дочерние окна. Без создания окна весь функционал прогрес бара придется реализовывать самостоятельно. Шрифт лучше создавать при создании окон. А еще можно использовать DEFAULT_GUI_FONT

Comment: Шрифт вынес, благодарю. По поводу прогресс бара посмотрю как смогу реализовать.